# How do I do advanced searches in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, search, finder, spotlight

I don't get it. I just want to do simple searches that work. When I type part of a filename, I want to see all the files that have that part of the filename. I know how to do this in terminal, but it takes time to open and then to track down the file once it finds it. Is there a way to do this from the Finder? I want to be able to do **.doc* and get all my docs, or hello*.txt and find all filenames of that form. Am I missing something obvious?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to do boolean searches from the Finder (filename:hello*.txt AND modified:4days) or something.

OSX Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

Comment: You can search for both `hello` and `.txt` to be part of the filename by selecting *File Name* and entering e.g. `hello .txt` (separated by space). Not the real thing, but useful anyway.

Comment: A couple of things that make integration with the terminal easier: Cdto ( http://code.google.com/p/cdto/ ) an application that opens a terminal window in the same directory as the front Finder window, and the "open" command which opens a file or folder from the command line as if you'd double clicked it in Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/132788/2008/04/spotlight2.html) to be very helpful. Examples:

- `this OR that` - returns matches to anything that contains `this` or `that`
- `this AND that` - returns matches to anything containing `this` and `that`
- `this kind:word` - returns matches to `this` that are Word documents (`.docx` or `.doc`)
- `name:this kind:word modified:<21/11/10`***** - returns files named `this` that are Word documents that were modified before 21 November 2010.
- `this NOT that name:test kind:pages created:1/1/11-13/1/11`***** - returns pages files named `this` that don't contain `that` created between 1 January 2011 and 13 January 2011.

******May be different based on your locale settings; I'm using Canadian English where it's dd/mm/yy, yours may differ.*

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tried this and for a while this wasn't actually finding the files it purported to, but it turns out that a near-root folder was for some reason in my exclude from spotlight list even though I don't recall putting it there. Now as best as I can tell, this seems to work well, except it still leaves out system files. Do you know of a way, without going into the whole click the plus, drop-down menu, etc. etc. business, to default force include system files?

Comment: @Philip I don't believe there is a way to set it to include system files by default, unfortunately. Glad I could help!

Comment: Great answer! I've been missing the advanced search since it disappeared in system 9 or whenever it was.

Answer (score 1):

Check out EasyFind, free from NCH Software. It searches *everything*, does Boolean searches, you can select where it searches, etc., etc. And it's fast. A go-to that I keep handy for when Spotlight just won't do.